# Benefits of using small and large sets instead of classes in category theory

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

I've been reading some category theory texts for my undergraduate monography, and I've found that one can talk about small and large categories using small/large sets, or do the same using sets/classes. Most introductory texts just shrug formalisms off, mention one of these formalizations and goes on.

I've noticed that most category-focused authors and texts (such as *Categories for the working mathematician* and *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* by Mac Lane) tend to prefer the small/large set approach, while texts that don't focus that much on categories (*Topology and Groupoids* by R. Brown) tend to prefer the class/set one.

My question:

Is there a categorical/set-theoretical reason to prefer the small sets approach?

I'd assume that there's a benefit in having a **set** of objects even in large categories, but fail to see an actual difference. I found the paper *Set Theory for Category Theory* by Michael Shulman, but it was way out of the scope of what I can understand.

Comment: what is the difference between a large set and a class??

Comment: @FShrike in many uses of the phrase there is no difference, though there is a distinction in the context of Grothendiek Universes (where a small set is contained in the universe, whereas a large set is still a set but is not properly contained)

Comment: Foundations are usually not considered in category theory, so there is almost never a need to distinguish your choice of foundations. The term "small set" is almost always used when the author simply wishes to emphasize that things are small enough to ignore foundations. For practical purposes, classes act basically the same as sets other than being somehow "bigger", so the nuance isn't all that important.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen How can a set make sense if it exists outside your universe of discourse? Sorry, I don’t know about foundations really.

Comment: I think this is just a terminological choice and if it matters to you, you need to check exactly what the author is taking these terms to mean. Some authors use the term "class" for a family of sets defined by a formula in the language of set theory, but Brown doesn't do that and is using class v. set in much the same way as Mac Lane uses large set v. small set. (There is a discussion of this in section 6 of Shulman's paper: it is worth skimming that even if you don't understand all the details.)

Comment: @FShrike a small set $x$ **belongs** to the universe $U$ (i.e. $x\in U$), while a large set may be a subset of the universe but not a member of it. For example, the universe itself is a set, but does not belong to the universe.

Comment: @FShrike: In the context of [Grothendieck set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski–Grothendieck_set_theory) "universe" doesn't mean "universe of discourse". The theory provides an infinite collection of what are called universes each of which is closed under all the set theoretic constructions of ZF set theory.